# Form action in angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I'm trying to setup login with angular.js and devise.

This is my form html:

```
<form ng-submit="submitLogin(loginForm)" role="form" ng-init="loginForm = {}">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" ng-model="loginForm.email" required="required" class="form-control"> </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ng-model="loginForm.password" required="required" class="form-control"> </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

So basically my form is always `POST`-ing to `/api/auth/sign_in`. However my api has a version in the path as well.

So `/api/v1/auth/sign_in` would work but not `/api/auth/sign_in`.

How can I change the form action to include the api version as well?

**Update, this is important angular related info**

```
angular
    .module('AngularRails', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngCookies',
        'ngResource',
        'ngRoute',
        'ngSanitize',
        'ngTouch',
        'templates', 
        'ng-token-auth'
    ]).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/app/sign_in', { 
                templateUrl: 'user_sessions/new.html', 
                controller: 'UserSessionsCtrl' 
            })
            .otherwise({
              redirectTo: '/'
            });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({
          enabled: true,
          requireBase: false
        });
    });
```

And `submitLogin` is from [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/ng-token-auth). Is there a way to configure or override the function `submitLogin` from ng-token-auth (Token based authentication module for angular.js)?

Comment: show me submitLogin() method code

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like
 `$scope.actionUrl = $scope.ContextUrl + '/api/v1/auth/sign_in';`
$scope.ContextUrl might be whatever you want to provide to make url reachable.

Or

```
<form action="{{ ContextUrl + '/api/v1/auth/sign_in' }}">
```

It's a dirty answer, try it and let me know.

Comment: thanks for the response. This didn't work, I was able to get the right path, but the `GET` request was performed and not `POST`

Comment: try method="POST" ,in <form>